# How to decompile an asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, decompiler

I have a website and i can open it with the VS 2010, but it has been compiled, i cannot find the app_code folder and the aspx.cs files. now i wanna see them and make some changes myself. I don't know how.

I know how to do it on a pure dll with the help of the reflector.

Does anyone here help me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you'd modify the compiled asp.net website, but here's how to find the dll's.

In your asp.net site you have for example an file called index.aspx, in your bin Directory there should be a file called something like `index.aspx.abcd1234.compiled`, open it with Notepad and look for the text `assembly="App_Web_y5emcutv"`, that's the name of the compiled code's dll, just look for that name in your bin directory and open the dll in reflector and look for the `ASP` namespace. 
That's it for the code, it would be rather hard to reverse that into a project file though.

Comment: thanks, i know what you mean, but i want a convenient way just like how we decompile a dll.

Comment: and that's what i described. you decompile every single page in the asp.net site like that.